# MS Access: I want a data entry-enabled form to auto populate an autonumber, at the moment all I'm getting is (New)

Tags: forms, ms-access, macros, vba

I have a popup form that fills in 4 fields that will be invisible in my form. Then I click a button, this opens a form with an autonumber field, before this was on a data entry form this autonumber field populated itself as I ran through the navigation, but since I only want the user to be able to have access to one field (I will have a button that will save and update the records instead of making a new one every time) I cannot have a record navigation.

From my little experience in access the only 3 ways I can imagine solving this (in the order I'd rather do them) are:

Have a way for a form to start up with a new record without data entry mode.

Having a way to populate the autonumber on the form whilst it generates in data entry mode.

Having a way for the button on the initial popup form to autoincrement the autonumber by 1 and set the autonumber as that.

MY update query is:

```
UPDATE AdvisorInput SET AdvisorInput.PSTNVolume = (([Forms]![frmInput]![txtPSTN])+([Forms]![frmInput]![txtPSTN2])), AdvisorInput.BBVolume = (([Forms]![frmInput]![txtBB])+([Forms]![frmInput]![txtBB2])), AdvisorInput.TVVolume = (([Forms]![frmInput]![txtTV])+([Forms]![frmInput]![txtTV2])), AdvisorInput.FibreVolume = (([Forms]![frmInput]![txtFibre])+([Forms]![frmInput]![txtFibre2])), AdvisorInput.C2FUVolume = (([Forms]![frmInput]![txtC2FU])+([Forms]![frmInput]![txtC2FU2])), AdvisorInput.PSTNCease = (([Forms]![frmInput]![txtPSTNCease])+([Forms]![frmInput]![txtPSTNCease2])), AdvisorInput.BBCease = (([Forms]![frmInput]![txtBBCease])+([Forms]![frmInput]![txtBBCease2])), AdvisorInput.TVCease = (([Forms]![frmInput]![txtTVCease])+([Forms]![frmInput]![txtTVCease2]))
WHERE (((AdvisorInput.AdvisorEIN)=[Forms]![frmInput]![txtEIN]) And ((AdvisorInput.CSS_WEEK)=[Forms]![frmInput]![txtCSSWeek]) And ((AdvisorInput.WeekdayName)=[Forms]![frmInput]![cboWeekday]));
```

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The `autonumber` field only gets a value when at least one field has been entered. You could have hidden field and enter the value using code.

BTW Once the autonumber field has used a number, the next time it will used the next number even if the previous record was deleted. Compacting the database resets the seed number to the maximum currently in the database, so does using an `INSERT` statement and explicitly inserting a value for the autonumber field.

To open a form with existing records directly with a new record:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

Comment: In data entry mode it only displays a blank record, the end scenario I want for this form is so that multiple users can use it at the same time whilst it feeds back the the main table. To do that I can't have any users having access to previous records. How would I make this hidden field's value the new increment? Would it basically be txthiddenID=table.ID.Column(0)+1?

Comment: You can have multiple users accessing a form at the same time even if they have access to previous records. Ms Access will lock any record if user starts editing it until the user moves to a different record.

Comment: If a form is bound to a table or (updateable) query then the autonumber field will automatically increment when a new record is added. That is the way to do it!

Comment: Right, as I understand it when I open a form it opens with record 1 of 7, I would like it to start with a new record, how can I do this?

Comment: It IS opening in a new record now (Which is great thanks, weirdly OnLoad got an error but OnOpen was fine) But the ID field is still (New) instead of the next number, I really appreciate all this help.

Comment: As in my answer, until some data is entered into another field the autonumber field will not get a value and will show `(New)`

Comment: I am still getting "This query will update 0 rows", it may be my update query being wrong now, I've edited my post showing my update query.

Comment: You should not be using an `UPDATE` query. You should set `Record Source` of the form to the table in question and use bound controls for all data that is to be shown or updated.

Comment: I want the form to write data onto a new record (if it isn't there) and then every time a user makes an input of 1 x sale or 1 y sale, this will record back to the right record,and clear the fields, although I'm sure I can manage to clear them myself.